# How to make DFS algorithm continue working on a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to search for a path(doesn't have to be the shortest path) on a 40 x 20 Graph. The starting and ending points are chosen randomly. The DFS works fine, until it hits and edge. Then, instead of going back and trying to search in the different direction, it just loops itself. Here's my code (small bit of it, but there isn't need for anymore to understand it, full code's here:

```
struct Wierzcholek {
    Wierzcholek* next;
    int numerwierzcholka;
};
bool DFS(Wierzcholek**& TablicaList, bool*& visited, int& startowy, int koncowy, int MacierzGrafu[Wymiar40][Wymiar20])

{
        Wierzcholek* p;
        visited[startowy] = true;

            cout << setw(3) << startowy << "->";
            /*
            if (startowy == koncowy)
            {
                cout << koncowy << setw(5) << "Function has ended";
                return true;
            }//*/
                for (p = TablicaList[startowy]; p; p = p->next)
                {
                    MacierzGrafu[startowy / 20][startowy % 20] = 2;
                    if (!visited[p->numerwierzcholka])
                        if(DFS(TablicaList, visited, p->numerwierzcholka, koncowy, MacierzGrafu));
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
}
//Here's the implementation in main function
do {
        DFS(TablicaList, visited, LosowyWierzcholek, KoncowyWierzcholek, MacierzGrafu);
            if (LosowyWierzcholek == KoncowyWierzcholek)
                break;
    } while(true);
```

Edit: Here is the full program: https://ideone.com/LGAhw1 and here is how i make the adjacency list:

```
void UwtorzSasiada(int MacierzGrafu[Wymiar40][Wymiar20], Wierzcholek **& TablicaList,const char Kierunek, int row, int column) // 68-D(1) 71-G(4) 76-L(9) 80-P(13)
{
    Wierzcholek* p;
    int variable = int(Kierunek) - 67;
    switch (variable)
    {
    case 1: {
        if (MacierzGrafu[row + 1][column] == 1)
        {
            p = new Wierzcholek;
            p->numerwierzcholka = (((row + 1) * Wymiar20) + column);
            p->next = TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column];
            TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column] = p;
        }
    }break;
    case 4: {
        if (MacierzGrafu[row - 1][column] == 1)
        {
            p = new Wierzcholek;
            p->numerwierzcholka = (((row - 1) * Wymiar20) + column);
            p->next = TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column];
            TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column] = p;
        }
    }break;
    case 9: {
        if (MacierzGrafu[row][column - 1] == 1)
        {
            p = new Wierzcholek;
            p->numerwierzcholka = ((row * Wymiar20) + column - 1);
            p->next = TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column];
            TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column] = p;
        }
    }break;
    case 13: {
        if (MacierzGrafu[row][column + 1] == 1)
        {
            p = new Wierzcholek;
            p->numerwierzcholka = ((row * Wymiar20) + column + 1);
            p->next = TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column];
            TablicaList[(row * Wymiar20) + column] = p;
        }
    }break;
    }
}
```

Comment: *how do i make the dfs continue searching instead of looping infinitely?* -- You shouldn't write a single line of code until you solve the issue on paper first.  Then translate that solution to code.

Comment: variable names can be of a great help when trying to read your code.. but not when they're in other langages. Next time, please translate them (or write them directly in english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

1. You put the base case of your recursion in comments, but it is needed to end the recursion with a positive outcome:

   ```
   if (startowy == koncowy) {
       cout << koncowy << setw(5) << "target found";
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. The result of the recursive `DFS` call is ignored, and instead `true` is returned unconditionally -- also when the node's neighbor had already been visited. This happens because the inner `if` statement has no body:

   ```
   if (!visited[p->numerwierzcholka])
       if(DFS(TablicaList, visited, p->numerwierzcholka, koncowy, MacierzGrafu));
   return true;
   ```

   The semicolon at the right side of the `if` is breaking the algorithm. This should be:

   ```
   if (!visited[p->numerwierzcholka] && 
           DFS(TablicaList, visited, p->numerwierzcholka, koncowy, MacierzGrafu))
       return true;
   ```
3. The `startowy` parameter never changes during a call of `DFS`, yet in your main code you seem to expect that the call will change `LosowyWierzcholek` until it eventually matches `KoncowyWierzcholek`. This is not true. `LosowyWierzcholek` will not change. So the `while` loop in your main program is an infinite loop.
4. The main program should not need a loop at all: the traversal happens through recursion, not through iteration. It doesn't help to repeat the same `DFS` search again.

   Instead, your main program should just call `DFS` and use the boolean return value:

   ```
   bool result = DFS(TablicaList, visited, LosowyWierzcholek, KoncowyWierzcholek, MacierzGrafu);
   cout << "result: " << result;
   ```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this answer, the algorithm you are talking about in 3rd paragraph is made so that when eventually the current vertex of the graph meets the one it's searching for, the function will stop. It doesn't change the `LosowyWierzcholek` but when dfs is called(eventually) with a parameter that is identical to `KoncowyWierzcholek` it should stop the recursion. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: I've applied the changes but the program still just ends when it meets an edge, so my initial problem is still unsolved unfortunately.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that builds the graph, so we can run it and see what happens? I just identified some problems that made your code hang, but obviously I could not run it, as it is not complete.

Comment: I've edited the question by putting how i create my list at the end  and also put a link to ideone if you want to run the program, as it is already chopped to functions and a bit too long to put in the question.